# A not-so-well-known movie on virtual reality

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember some ten years ago I watched an old western movie about virtual reality similar to "Matrix" and "The Thirteenth Floor".

In the movie, a computer game designer (or player?) lives in a computerized house and the computer will give him "suggestions" (instructions) on what to on everything in his daily life, and he usually follows the "suggestions".

He himself is playing a computer game in which he gives instructions to the man in the game. The movie seemed to suggest that eventually he realized that he is himself inside a computer game and the "computer" of his house is in fact the upper-level player.

In particular remember that the man finally found that he, for some reason I can't remember, had to go to Mumbai in order to escape from his computer world.

I have googled for a long time but cannot find what this movie is. It seems that it's not a very well-known movie.

Comment: Hi! Do you remember the approximate year\decade of release? Any other characters and the people who played them?

Comment: Also "western" is a little imprecise...US/English/European? Any chance of narrowing that down?

Comment: I think it should be the 90's, because in the movie Mumbai is still called Bombay. The movie is in English, but I don't know whether it's US or Britain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending differs from what you described, but it could be [*Nirvana*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119794/plotsummary) :

Jimi designs a game where he controls the main character, Solo, by telling him what to do. Solo becomes sentient and feels the pain from every death he experiences ingame. When Jimi next tries to play, Solo refuses to obey, and then asks his creator to destroy the game, so to bring a stop to his suffering.

Do accomplish this, Jimi has to go to Bombay and enter the company server to destroy the game. To navigate the virtual reality inside the server, Jimi has to free his mind, achieving Nirvana.

I couldn't find any English speaking clips of the movie, but there is a Russian dubbed full version here:

Comment: Mumbai is Bombay.

Comment: Did not know that. City names in other languages always confuse me. Thanks!

Comment: Many Indian cities and provinces had their original names changed while they were colonies and are only recently being officially renamed to their original names. Mumbai was renamed back from Bombay in 1996, and others, like Madras, went back to original name of Chennai only a couple of years ago. Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaming_of_cities_in_India

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be looking for the film that *The Thirteenth Floor* was originally based on, *[World on a Wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_on_a_Wire)* (*Welt Am Draht*).

It was originally a German television miniseries from 1973, and then was retreated and rereleased on DVD and shown at several different film festivals. It was also shown on television (Turner Classic Movies) in 2014, which I realize is later than your "some 10 years ago".

The plot is similar, in that there is a simulation program, and one of the central themes is to make contact with the "higher level" simulation.

Here is a brief synopsis from a review and discussion of the director ([Roger Ebert's site](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/world-on-a-wire-2011)):

> The story centers on Stiller (Klaus Löwitsch), an engineer who works for a program named Simulacron, which fabricates complete identities for characters who don't know they're unreal. In the film, Stiller and others discuss the notion that reality is unreal, tracing it to Plato. The purpose of Simulacron is said to be the prediction of consumer trends 20 years into the future, although there may be a more sinister purpose. It's possible to imagine all the creatures inside Simulacron as living in a sort of SimCity controlled from a higher level. Or are perhaps the fabricators of Simulacron themselves manipulated by still higher puppet masters?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately it is not the one I am looking for.

Answer (score -4):

Dont really know the movie but this might be it -> 
The eccentric Dr. Lawrence Angelo (Pierce Brosnan) puts mentally disabled landscaper Jobe Smith (Jeff Fahey) on a regimen of experimental pills and computer-simulated training sequences in hopes of augmenting the man's intelligence. In time Jobe becomes noticeably brighter and also begins to fare much better with the opposite sex. But, as he develops psychic powers, he realizes that those around him have taken advantage of his simplicity his whole life, and he plots a bloody revenge.

Comment: Thank you! But I am quite sure this is not the one I watched. PS I didn't downvote : )

Comment: @angelheart87 The reason your answer(s) are attracting downvotes is because you appear to be *guessing without considering the details the OP has provided*  You appear to be throwing up any older movie that involves VR, but the OP said he's spent a significant amount of time on Google, so the odds that he's already found and discounted the top 10 results of "VR movie + ten years ago" is pretty high.  Try to find something that matches **all the details the OP mentioned**.

Comment: Ok sorry about that i didnt know..